# Visual Studio 2013 error LNK2019

Tags: c++, lua, visual-studio-2013, linker-errors

I really have a problem which I just don't understand why it is there.
I want to use LUA as a Scripting language to embed it into C++ applications.

I have downloaded the LUA-binaries (Version 5.2.3 win64 vc12; at the time of writing, the newest).

First I tried out a simple "Hello World" that Looks like this:

main.cpp:

> ```
> #pragma comment(lib, "lua52")
>
> #include <stdio.h>
> #include "lua.hpp"
>
> int main(int argc, char* argv[])
> {
>   printf("Hello World of c++\n");
>
>   lua_State* L = luaL_newstate();
>
>   luaopen_base(L);
>
>   if (luaL_dofile(L, "test01.lua"))
>   {
>       printf("%s\n", lua_tostring(L, -1));
>   }
>
>   lua_close(L);
>
>   getchar();
>
>   return 0;
> }
> ```

test01.lua:

> print("Hello World of LUA\n")

As you can see it is a very simple code.

I have edited the include directories to include the Path of the header-files and I have edited the library directories to include the path to the library `lua52.lib`.

But for some reason I get the error: "error LNK2019..."

I hope someone knows what to do.

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Comment: As you are using 64-bit library, check what your program build platform is `x64` (64-bit). If they mismatch, then you get link errors.

Comment: @Rimas, thank you so much that was exactly what was going wrong... I never looked at the build platform (stupid me)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "bitness" needs to correspond, the library and the target need to be built to the same target platform; so for the 64-bit library, your binary is also required to be 64-bit; the same applies for the 32-bit version(s).

---

You will need to link the library;

```
#pragma comment(lib, "lua52.lib") // note the .lib
```

The question was tagged as C++. Lua seems to be [implemented in C](http://lua-users.org/wiki/BuildingLua), so in your C++ application (if compiled as such; which is the default), you may need to include it as;

```
extern "C" {
  #include "lua.hpp"
}
```

Comment: I really hoped it would be such a stupid mistake of mine. unfortunatelly it still doesnt work

Comment: @Zydar, You probably have more missing libraries. What symbols is it not finding?

Comment: i thought about more missing libraries too. I just cant figure out which ones. The symbols it is not finding are: "luaL_newstate" , "luaL_loadfilex" , "luaopen_base" , "lua_pcallk" , "lua_tolstring" and "lua_close"

Comment: Yes, that's the Content of the included lua.hpp file.

Comment: Still the same, no changes.

Comment: Is it possible that the LUA-binaries aren't compatible with VS2013?

Comment: @Zydar, possible but they should still link. Are you building and linking to the correct bitness (32 vs 64 bit)?

Comment: yes that was the Problem, I was using a 32 bit build platform.. so now I included the win32 binaries of LUA and it's working now

Comment: `extern "C" { #include "lua.hpp" }` is not needed as `extern "C"` already is in `lua.hpp`